# the table 'sales_quote_address' is no longer exists in 1.7 above

Tags: checkout, upgrade, sales, magento-1.7, flat

I found in 1.7 and 1.8 the table 'sales_quote_address'is no longer exist.
Then which table does the code 'Mage:getModel('sales/quote_address')' loaded?
How can I add one more column to the 'sale_flat_quote_address' table?

Comment: You must be looking at non complete database. The table in question is in 1.7, 1.8 and EE 1.13

Comment: You have confused Adam, this table exists in all versions of Magento, event in Magento 2

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the comments this table should be there. You could try using the [Magento Database Repair Tool](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/db-repair-tool) to fill in the gaps that you have the current database structure. There are many mixed reviews as if this tool works, the following steps are the basic usage.

1. Install the same version of Magento you’re using into a clean database,
2. The new database is called your "Reference Database",
3. The current database (with missing tables) is called your "Corrupted Database",

After running this tool you should then have a new database with the complete structure plus all your current data.

Comment: It does not matter it exists or not, the addColumn($installer->getTable('sales/quote_address') did add column to sales_flat_quote_address, not sales_quote_address table in ce-1.7 above.  I just solve the problem of upgrading my extension to ce-1.7 above.

Comment: The eav_entity_type table does not have the 'sale/quote_address' entity model in ce-1.7 above so the table sales_quote_address is no longer exist. Am I right?

Comment: I also check my Ubuntu VM and use svn to download the magento1.8 and run it. The database also does not have the sales_quote_address table, only its flat table.  I do not know when they change it to only the flat table.  Is there any way to restore sales_quote_address table?

Comment: Conclusion: My extension only works with the sample data sql because its eav_entity_type table has 30 rows of data.  And ce-1.7 above without sample data sql, its eav_entity_type table only has 8 rows of data. I am working on making my extension work without the sample data sql.